# receive wireless data through laptop network card in matlab

Tags: matlab, signals, wifi, data-acquisition, acquisition

i am doing a project in which i have to *acquire* the **wireless signal** transmitted through **wifi/router**.

> But the signal acquisition has to be done in **MATLAB**, for doing frequency operations.

Can anyone give me some useful link or some **MATLAB** guideline to do so.

Answer (score 1):

A standard wifi adapter is not able to capture the raw analogue signal, you need some hardware which can do this. This hardware will probably come with a c or c++ api, which can be used via mex functions.

[How to capture raw signal from wireless router?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17264118/how-to-capture-raw-signal-from-wireless-router)